# Sharepoint web services GetListItems view name

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I need to figure out my view name that I need to query (NOT programmatically). I know the list name is "MyList", but I also need to know the view name so I can pass that as the second parameter. Only thing I've found is people passing the GUID for the view name, how do I get the "friendly" name of the view?

```
SharepointWebService.GetListItems("MyList", "MyView", 
    xmlNodeQuery, xmlNodeViewFields, "1000", null, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to perform an additional query to find the GUID for that view.

You can use the [GetViewCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/views.views.getviewcollection%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method from views.asmx to get all of the views for a particular list.  The return results has the `DisplayName`, which is the plain text name you need, as well as the `Name`, which is the GUID.  You can find the GUID for the list you need within those results so that you can use that GUID in subsequent calls to `GetListItems`.

Comment: Does the GetListItems method call require a GUID?

Comment: @ganders No, you can provide an empty string and it will use the default view, as [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems(v=office.12).aspx) states.  What you can't do is specify a view by title, which is what you said you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, got the Display name which happened to be the same thing that I was trying before I asked the question. I then used the GUID instead and it's still returning all items that show up in the Default view...I'll update my question with all of my code.

Comment: @ganders If you're passing the GUID and that's not working then perhaps you're not formatting it properly; i.e. you're including the braces when you shouldn't or missing them if you should have them, you don't have the dashes right, you have the braces escaped in some way, etc.

Comment: You're right, I was setting my ndQuery parameter with stuff from a different query which was making my result set return results that looked like the default view. Once I cleared out ALL of that, it works. Thanks for your help.